# Javascript onsubmit clearcontent not working

Tags: javascript

```
<textarea onfocus=" javascript:clearContents(this); this.cleared=true;" rows="5" cols="40" id="comment" name="comment" <?php if($vis["username"] == $pusername) { echo "DISABLED"; } ?>>...</textarea>
<input onsubmit="if (!this.comment.cleared) clearContents(this.comment); return true;" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Stem!"/> 

function clearContents(element) {
  element.innerHTML = '';
}
```

This wont work, and i cant figure out why. What it does: clears the content if it hasnt been onfocus/clicked on by the person

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
clearContents( document.getElementById('comment') )
```

You should bind `onsubmit` to the `<form>` and do this unobtrusively, ideally...

Answer (score 1):

```
<input onsubmit="if (!this.comment.cleared)
```

`this` is the `<input>`. Input elements don't have a `submit` event or a `comment` property. Probably you want to put this on the surrounding `<form>` element:

```
<form onsubmit="if (!this.comment.cleared) ...
```

Whilst it is possible to put it on the submit button, you'd have to use `onclick="if (!this.form.comment.cleared) ...`, to navigate up to the form and down to the other input. It's not generally a good idea to tie form submission code to a particular button.

As meder said, doing all this in inline event handlers is a bit ugly. (Especially the unnecessary `javascript:` prefix.) Prefer to assign from JS instead:

```
<form id="someform" method="post" action="somewhere"><div>
    <textarea
        rows="5" cols="40" name="comment"
        <?php if($vis['username']==$pusername) { ?>disabled="disabled"<?php } ?>
    >
        ...
    </textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Stem!" />
</div></form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var f= document.getElementById('someform');
    var cleared= false;
    f.elements.comment.onfocus= function() {
        f.comment.value= '';
        cleared= true;
    };
    f.onsubmit= function() {
        if (!cleared)
            f.comment.value= '';
    };
</script>
```

I've used XHTML syntax for the disabled attribute (since you seem to be using XHTML syntax elsewhere), and used `value` to clear the content. Don't use `innerHTML`—it doesn't do what you think, except when it coincidentally does due to browser bugs. Form fields should always be accessed using `value`.